# How to write a new type that is compatible with Array.sum?

Tags: f#

```
type Foo(...) =
    ...

let a = Array.create 10 (new Foo())

let sum = Array.sum a
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add a few members that are used by the `sum` function to do the calculation:

```
type Foo(value:int) = 
  member x.Value = value
  // Two members that are needed by 'Array.sum'
  static member (+) (a:Foo, b:Foo) = Foo(a.Value + b.Value)
  static member Zero = Foo(0)
  // Not needed for 'Array.sum', but allows 'Array.average'
  static member DivideByInt(a:Foo, n:int) = Foo(a.Value / n)
```

The `sum` function starts with the value returned by `Zero` and then adds values of `Foo` using the overloaded `+` operator (`average` then divides the result by an integer):

```
let a = Array.init 10 (fun n -> Foo(n)) 
let sum = Array.sum a 
sum.Value // Returns 45
```

Comment: Thanks! BTW, how about implementing member `Cos` on a type, so that it works with `Core.Operators.cos` too?

Comment: @Stringer: Supporting `cos` is possible too (the member declaration would be `static member Cos(a:Foo) = a` - note that it has to return value of type `Foo` as the result). There are quite a few standard library functions that can be supported using members...

Answer (score -1):

Not possible.

When you want to use any method of Array (sum, etc), you must use an array type for the data storage.

**EDIT: I misinterpreted your question. You might want to try to implement certain operator overloads such as +, - etc. Maybe the type would then support the sum method.**